# Как передавать значения переменной?

Tags: php

```
<html>
```

<body>

<?php
   if($_POST['connect_db']) //если нажата кнопка соединиться с сервером баз
    {

```
$link=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); //параметры подключения

if (!$link)  //если не подключились выводим сообщение
    {
    echo "Не могу подключиться к серверу с базами";
    exit();
    }
if ($link)  //если подключились выводим сообщение
    {
    echo "Подключился к серверу с базами";
    }

}
```

if($_POST['creat_db']) //если нажата кнопка создать бд
    {
    //if (!mysql_create_db("test_db", $link) )
    //  {
    //  echo "Не могу создать базу";
    //  exit();
    //  }
    //  echo "Все ништяк база создана";
echo $link;
    }

?>

<form method="POST" >

```
 <input type="submit" name="connect_db" value="Подключиться к бд">
 <input type="submit" name="creat_db" value="Создать бд">
```

</form>
</body>
</html>

такой вопрос, почему когда после нажатия кнопки подключиться к БД ... пропадает данные из переменной $link ? Ведь я хочу после воспользоваться этой переменной чтобы создать БД,
Как передавать тогда этот параметр и как его забирать? Я вообще 0,0001 в РНР  спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 2):

вынеси $link=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); за пределы if и все, то есть поставь после открывающегося тега body